# Construct a type that only accepts object types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Is there any way I can create a type alias that excludes every single basic type (`string`, `number`, `boolean` etc.) and only accept an object type? (like `{}` or `[]`)

Comment: `Array<any> | Record<any, any>;`?

Comment: Are you sure you need a type alias?  It sounds like you are describing the `object` type.

Comment: @dave Thats exactly it! I knew I needed a Utility Type but couldn't figure out which one.

Comment: @CaseyRule I tried with the Object type but it kept accepting strings and numbers. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

For generic types you can use the extends keyword to restrict the type wich can be passed as a generic type

```
type OnlyStrOrArr<T extends object | Array<any>> = T;
```

If you try to pass another type, Typescript will throw an error.

This works also with generics of other types like classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, there is a difference between the `Object` and `object` types.  What you want is the lowercase [`object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) which was introduced in 2.2.  This type specifically represents any non-primitive value.